# Correct way to store this token

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I'm writing my first flask app and using the spotify api. I want to pass the access token from this api into java script like so

```
  var token = "{{ token }}";
  fetch('https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/currently- 
   playing', {
        headers: {
           'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
        }
```

I'm doing this outside the flask app so I can frequently update the json data to the webpage easier. This method doesn't seem secure so I was wondering what is the perferred method in a situation like this.

Comment: well no matter what if you are making a call on the clientside, the token is going to be visible.

Comment: get params are not exposed if using ssl

Comment: what your doing is fine ... sometimes people store the token in a database or something or in a separate creds file ... sometimes they encrypt the token (but you still need to store the decrypt key)

Answer (score 0):

Since your example is almost literally straight out of the [Spotify Authorization Documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/) and it is in relation to accessing the Web API, you're good. 
If you were auth'ing on behalf of a user for more serious actions then you wouldn't be making client side requests. 
Since the token you're using can be revoked and does in fact expire, you can store it in your db in plaintext.

Answer (score -1):

You can store keys/secrets using Microsoft's Azure Software. Once you register you'll have access to those resources. You can set the secret in the secrets file in your azure portal and reference the secrets from there in your application source code.

Comment: i dont think this answers the question at all